# How to add a logo inside a block's title

Tags: beamer, graphics, block

I'm trying to include a logo inside a block's title (the document is a presentation using the Berkeley theme):

```
\begin{block} { \includegraphics[width=16pt,height=16pt]{blender.png} Blender }
            Free open source 3D cross-platform software under GNU Public License, used for creating 3D models, animations, particle systems...
\end{block}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Like you see the logo is badly aligned. It should be at the same height of the title's text, and it should also have a right margin. How to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to move the image box. For example

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=16pt,height=16pt]{example-image-a}} \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\hbox{Blender}}
```

will center the heights of the two boxes.

[image: Output]

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=16pt,height=16pt]{example-image-a} Blender

\bigskip

\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=16pt,height=16pt]{example-image-a}} \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\hbox{Blender}}

\bigskip

\raisebox{-.25\height}{\includegraphics[width=16pt,height=16pt]{example-image-a}} Blender

\bigskip

\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=16pt,height=16pt]{example-image-a}} Blender

\end{document}
```

[image: Again, output for the MWE]